# On adding <header/> to layout.tsx to display header in every page. layout.tsx is in app directory ising app router in nextjs gives me following errors

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i made some changes to layout.tsx as follows.
not able to use next router as cant use it in server components.i had to comment out metadata which i dont want to just to ignore the server component error

```
'use client'
import { hydrateRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'


import MainHeader from './layout/main-header'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

// export const metadata = {
//   title: 'Create Next App',
//   description: 'Generated by create next app',
// }

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  const excludeHeader = pathname.startsWith('/admin')

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      {!excludeHeader && <MainHeader />}
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

having following error

```
expected server HTML to contain a matching <header> in <html>.
    at header
    at MainHeader (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./app/layout/main-header.jsx:21:80)
    at html
    at RootLayout (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./app/layout.tsx:23:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:33:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:40:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:276:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:90:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:62:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:87:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:372:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:154:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:171:11)
w
```

header component is as follows,i dont think it has anything to do with the error .

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import { NavLink, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import ModalLogin from "../components/Login";
import {
  faMagnifyingGlass,
  faBars,
  faTimes,
} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

function MainHeader() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const handleShowModal = () => {
    setShowModal(true);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setShowModal(false);
  };

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };
  return (
<Fragment>
    <header className="border-b md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between p-4 pb-0 shadow-lg md:pb-4">
      {/* Logo text or image */}
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between mb-4 md:mb-0">
        <h1 className="leading-none text-2xl text-grey-darkest">
          <Link
            href="/"
            className="no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-black"
          >
            Preview
          </Link>
        </h1>
        <button
          className="text-black hover:text-orange md:hidden"
          onClick={toggleMenu}
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={isOpen ? faTimes : faBars} />
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* END Logo text or image */}
      {/* nav*/}
      <nav className={`md:block ${isOpen ? "block" : "hidden"}`}>
        <ul className="list-reset md:flex md:items-center">
          <li className="md:ml-4">
            <Link
              className="block no-underline hover:underline py-2 text-grey-darkest hover:text-black md:border-none md:p-0"
              href="/"
            >
              Home
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="md:ml-4">
            <Link
              className="border-t block no-underline hover:underline py-2 text-grey-darkest hover:text-black md:border-none md:p-0"
              href="/category"
            >
              Category
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="md:ml-4">
            <Link
              className="border-t block no-underline hover:underline py-2 text-grey-darkest hover:text-black md:border-none md:p-0"
              href="/product"
            >
              products
            </Link>
          </li>
          {/* <li className="md:ml-4">
            <Link
              className="border-t block no-underline hover:underline py-2 text-grey-darkest hover:text-black md:border-none md:p-0"
              href="/blog"
            >
              Blog
            </Link>
          </li> */}
          <li className="md:ml-4">
            <Link
              className="border-t block no-underline hover:underline py-2 text-grey-darkest hover:text-black md:border-none md:p-0"
              href="/about"
            >
              About
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li className="md:ml-4">
            <div>
              <button onClick={handleShowModal}>Login</button>
              {showModal && <ModalLogin onClose={handleCloseModal} />}
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      {/* END Search field */}
      {/* search */}

      <button
        type="button"
        className=" bg-purple-800 hover:bg-purple-900 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-purple-300 font-medium  text-white text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center  dark:bg-purple-300 dark:hover:bg-purple-600 dark:focus:bg-purple-900"
      >
        <Link href="/add-product"> Add a Product </Link>
      </button>
      {/* <form className="mb-4 md:mb-0 md:w-1/4">
          <label className="hidden" htmlFor="search-form">Search</label>
          <input className="bg-grey-lightest border-2 focus:border-orange p-2 rounded-lg shadow-inner w-full" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
          <button className="hidden">Submit</button>
        </form> */}
      {/* END Global navigation */}
    </header>
</Fragment>
  );
}

export default MainHeader;
```

Comment: Can you share the code of your `MainHeader` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to add a `header` tag inside a `html` tag. This is not allowed, see the [MDN html docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html). You should be adding the `header` to the `body`.

```js
<html lang="en">
  <body className={inter.className}>
    {!excludeHeader && <MainHeader />}
    {children}
  </body>
</html>
```